# N-th power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to find the n-th power for the following matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1+\sqrt3 & 1-\sqrt3\\ \sqrt3 - 1 & \sqrt3 +1\end{pmatrix}
$$ My thoughts is that here could be the same situation as for $B=\begin{pmatrix} \sin x & - \cos x\\ \cos x & \sin x\end{pmatrix}
$ which give  $$B^n=\begin{pmatrix} \sin (nx) & - \cos (nx) \\ \cos (nx) & \sin (nx) \end{pmatrix}.
$$ So I think I have to make a connection between A and B, however in A I dont have only $1$ term per place so I dont know how to proceed. $$\frac12 A=\begin{pmatrix} \sin(\pi /6) +\cos(\pi /6) &\sin(\pi /6) - \cos(\pi /6)   \\ \cos(\pi /6) - \sin(\pi /6)   &\sin(\pi /6) +\cos(\pi /6)   \end{pmatrix}
$$ Couls you help me?

Comment: Is it  diagonalizable?

Comment: What is a rotation matrix?

Comment: Try pulling out a different common factor. You want the rows/columns of the matrix to end up being unit vectors.

Comment: A rotation matrix is one like $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be easily verified 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & -b\\
b & a
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sin\theta & -\cos\theta\\
\cos\theta & \sin\theta
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
b\cos\theta+a\sin\theta & a\cos\theta-b\sin\theta\\
-a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta & b\cos\theta+a\sin\theta
\end{array}\right)
$$

but

$$
b\cos\theta+a\sin\theta=\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\cos\theta+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}\sin\theta\right)=\rho\cos\left(\theta_{0}-\theta\right)
$$

and then

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
b\cos\theta+a\sin\theta & a\cos\theta-b\sin\theta\\
-a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta & b\cos\theta+a\sin\theta
\end{array}\right)=\rho\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\left(\theta_{0}-\theta\right) & \sin\left(\theta_{0}-\theta\right)\\
-\sin\left(\theta_{0}-\theta\right) & \cos\left(\theta_{0}-\theta\right)
\end{array}\right)
$$

so

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & -b\\
b & a
\end{array}\right)=\rho\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sin\theta & -\cos\theta\\
\cos\theta & \sin\theta
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\left(\theta_{0}-\theta\right) & \sin\left(\theta_{0}-\theta\right)\\
-\sin\left(\theta_{0}-\theta\right) & \cos\left(\theta_{0}-\theta\right)
\end{array}\right)=\rho\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sin\theta_{0} & -\cos\theta_{0}\\
\cos\theta_{0} & \sin\theta_{0}
\end{array}\right)
$$

hence

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & -b\\
b & a
\end{array}\right)^{n}=\rho^{n}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sin\left(n\theta_{0}\right) & -\cos\left(n\theta_{0}\right)\\
\cos\left(n\theta_{0}\right) & \sin\left(n\theta_{0}\right)
\end{array}\right)
$$

with

$$
\theta_0 = \arctan\left(\frac ab\right)\\
\rho = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You’re on the right track by trying to pull out a common scalar factor. You just have to use a different one. Hint: A key feature of $B$ is that its rows and columns are unit vectors, so see if both rows of $A$ have the same norm. You will then have $A = kB$, from which $A^n=k^nB^n$.

Comment: In this case, $k=\sqrt 2$?

Comment: @Sonkun No, but close. It’s $\sqrt{(1+\sqrt3)^2+(1-\sqrt3)^2}$. After factoring this out, you’ll likely also need Jacky Chong’s hint to find the angle $x$ for $B$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
\sin(\pi/6)+\cos(\pi/6) =& \sqrt{2}\left(\frac{\sin(\pi/6)}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\cos(\pi/6)}{\sqrt{2}} \right)\\
=&\sqrt{2}\left(\sin(\pi/6)\sin(\pi/4)+\cos(\pi/6)\cos(\pi/4)\right)=\ldots
\end{align}

Comment: that is $\sqrt 2 \cos (\pi/6 - \pi/4)$ right? Oh so I have to find similar values for the other $3$ places.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac12 A=\begin{pmatrix} \sin(\pi /6) +\cos(\pi /6) &\sin(\pi /6) - \cos(\pi /6)   \\ \cos(\pi /6) - \sin(\pi /6)   &\sin(\pi /6) +\cos(\pi /6)   \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\frac12  A= \begin{pmatrix} \sin(\pi /6)  &\cos(\pi /6)   \\ \cos(\pi /6)    &-\sin(\pi /6)    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1  &1   \\ 1    &-1    \end{pmatrix}$$